# How do you have static fields when using JSONPath?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, transformation, jsonpath

I have been using a the library [jsonpath-object-transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-object-transform), which is based on [JSONPath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath) to perform template based transformation of my JSON objects.

However, I am stuck at having a combination of dynamic fields and static fields.

As an example, I require the following output:

```
data = [
   {
      stroke: '4',
      name: 'line_1'
   },
   {
      stroke: '4',
      name: 'line_2'
   }
]
```

I need the 'name' field to be dynamic, populated by the JSONPath transformation, but I need each object to also contain a 'stroke' field with a constant value (4 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a static field escaping the value in backticks:

```
something.{field: dynamicField, staticNumber: `3`, staticText: `"hello"`}
```